# Is Heroku restart better than or the same as re-pushing the entire repository?

Tags: python, flask, heroku

What I mean by the title is is `heroku restart` more effective or permanent for resolving random crashing.

I have a [Heroku](http://searchenginecapstone.herokuapp.com/) app that randomly crashes and then starts working again without any indication as to why. This is the error message and it seems to crop up if no one has tried to access the webpage for about a day or so.

```
2022-12-12T16:04:02.145633+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=searchenginecapstone.herokuapp.com request_id=f44f9b0a-696d-468b-b39f-1e623dc35b5a fwd="68.49.171.116" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2022-12-12T16:06:02.812237+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=HEAD path="/" host=searchenginecapstone.herokuapp.com request_id=5d67f097-57ef-43e7-9b52-9e3b5609e394 fwd="217.182.175.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

Any idea how I can resolve this? I'm not sure what is sourcing this error. I was getting this error yesterday and once I subscribed to the $5 dyno package, it worked again. But now it's not working again.

If I redo the heroku deployment with
`git push origin master` after reinitializing git on the CLI and `git remote -v` then it works again, but I don't want to have to rely on that. I want it up 24/7.

Would `heroku restart` be a better way to permanently fix this issue, or is this the same as re-initializing the git repo and pushing the whole thing to the server again?

Here is the [Git Repo](https://github.com/TrevBot17/Capstone) with all the whole codebase

Comment: Pushing the same code again shouldn't do anything except (maybe) restart your running dynos. Neither of those has any permanent effect. You'll need to identify the root cause and fix it, but we can't help without way more information. At bare minimum, please add a tag for the language you are using, and framework if applicable. And you'll need to give us detailed logs from above the ones you've shared here.

Comment: Okay no problem. Also sorry, I thought I had added way more tags initially.

Comment: @Chris added a link to the Git Repository with all of the source code. Unfortunately that was literally the only error in the logs

Comment: The source code is helpful (having the relevant code directly in the question would be better) but without additional information from the logs we'd just be guessing. I suggest you add some logging to your handler for the `/` route and see if you can generate more detail.

Comment: I got an updated version of the error @Chris